# SQLDependency throwing thousands of invalid notifications with stored proc

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqldependency

I've built a vb.net service to update Exchange appointments as appointment changes are made in our accounting suite. Everything works fine if I run the SQL query straight from VB.net but if I reference a stored proc with the exact same code I receive thousands of "invalid" notifications. I was wondering if anyone could tell me why?

I'm using VS2012, SQL Server 2008, and .NET 4.0

I pass each "option" into the query string and execute it before starting the dependency with this query:

```
select Dispatch_Id, Schedule_Time, Dispatch_Time, Arrival_Time, Departure_Time from dbo.Ticket_Dispatch
```

The stored proc is:

```
USE [database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[watch]    Script Date: 1/22/2014 5:28:28 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[watch] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN

SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET ANSI_PADDING ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;

select Dispatch_Id, Schedule_Time, Dispatch_Time, Arrival_Time, Departure_Time from dbo.Ticket_Dispatch

END
```

Before any of this I test for permissions. The user has ownership over the table and the proc so there shouldn't be any problems there.

Comment: "I pass each "option" into the query string and execute it before starting the dependency " - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. In VB when I enter the SQL directly into the command text, before hand I'm setting my command text to "SET ANSI_NULLS ON", executing it, setting the command text to "SET ANSI_PADDING ON", executing, etc. for each of the 7 "options" (SQLDependency calls them options?). I seem to have to do this or it throws the bad options notification.